# How to compare if list of items are present in each row of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `data_file` of size 88k rows with 76 columns.

I want to compare if a list: `subset` = [40,49] is present in how many rows

I am comparing one row at a time as shown below:

My Code:

```
counter=0
for row in data_file.itertuples():
    if all(np.isin(subset, row)):
        counter = counter+1
print('Total occurences of subset: ', subset, '= ', counter)
print('--------------------------')
```

Execution time: 6.6398055266834035

Is there a better way to compare all rows at a time and save some time. I need to check may subsets so the time complexity of my code is high.

Thanks,

Gopi

Comment: I was able to write this `np.sum([ all(np.isin(subset, row)) for row in data_file.itertuples()])` but the execution time is still same

Comment: I can't imagine it will do much, but instead of counter = counter + 1, you can do counter +=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.sum((data_file==subset[0]).any(axis=1) & (data_file==subset[1]).any(axis=1))
```

Comment: This worked great @Sam17, exexution time is 0.27 secs. Can you explain how this line works. I am new to python

Comment: I divided your code into multiple lines to understand, You found` subset matches` separately and took `logical AND` of them and finally took the `sum` of` final boolean` to get this.. thanks...

Comment: (data_file==subset[0]).any(axis=1) compares each element in the dataframe with the number and returns a boolean series with True when the number is in the row or False if its not.